# Excel sheets treats declared string as number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript with React.js. Even though I declared variables' type as string in my interface, when I upload Excel sheet, if there is a number, it treats it as number. All I need to treat it as string.

```
let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
    header: headers,
    range: 1
}) as Array<Types.IExcelCourseRow>;
```

My `IExcelCourseRow` is:

```
{
    courseCode?: string;
    ...
}
```

Whenever my `courseCode` is `123`, it treats is as `123`. I need it to treat `courseCode` as `'123'`. What can I do?

Comment: Will you able to show your sample json output and more about xl to json conversion code

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave sample json output is following:
`courseCode: 123,
courseName: 'Math'` and I use ready xlsx react library.

Comment: Would you try this as a 2nd argument in XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json {
  blankrows: false,
  header: 'A',
  raw: true,
  rawNumbers: true
}

Comment: it didn't accept rawNumbers, saying `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'rawNumbers' does not exist in type 'Sheet2JSONOpts'`. so I tried `let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
        header: headers,
        range: 1,
        blankrows: false,
        raw: true,
      }) as Array<Types.IExcelCourseRow>;`
didn't work.

Comment: yesterday I was reading some issues, and articles regarding the same will you once try with keeping raw: false,    https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/169,

Comment: and if it is possible please add your code in codepen, stackblitz, or similar so we might directly make changes in that and try out more options with feasibility

Comment: I tried `raw:false` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a small bug in `sheet_to_json`, keeping `{ raw: false }` will resolve your problem.

[here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/169) is the link for more discussion on this issue

Answer (score -1):

Type validation in TypeScript only happens on compile time. So anything that happens on runtime, like (up)loading an excel file, will not help you out here. If you want to make sure that courseCode is a string, you'll have to type cast it yourself.

Comment: The issue at hand has to do with the driver(XLSX), and how it passes the value back to the  user code. Similar problems will be found with dates and how they're handled and what their cell format is within the spreadsheet. Typecasting a number will still yield incorrect result, e.g if the number started with 0, '056' , that 0 would be omitted , so even if you type casted , it would be incorrect, hence has to be configured on the driver to handle correctly.